# Why can't I create JSP files in Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 with Java Web Developer tools installed?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, web

I'm unable to create a JSP file using the wizard. I am using eclipse 4.2.2 Juno, it is Java J2EE IDE, I have also installed the Java Web Developer tools, but for some reason the option for creating a JSP file does not appear.

[image: Eclipse installation details with Java developer tools]

[image: Eclipse version Juno service release 2]

[image: New file Wizard but no JSP option available]

Does anyone have any ideas or things I may have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Please check *Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools*, shown below:

[image: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools]

If it is not there, you should install it by following steps:

- Help --> Install New Software
- Select Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
- Select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development --> Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools

Comment: "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" already installed for the same i have attached the screenshot.